# Single page website, want to strip #sections from url (example website given)

Tags: html, .htaccess

For a singlepage website, how do some of those websites strip that #section id from the url?

For example: http://www.formationstone.com/

There's no /#about-us; it's just showing the root domain on every subsesuent click from their menu.

I think it may have to do with htaccess, but I can't find the relevant code where I only want my root domain showing on all links.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are not stripping it, they just use a javascript onclick event to prevent the actual default event of the link and scroll to the headline. If you go to http://www.formationstone.com/#about the hash stays.

Let's have a look at the source code.

This is the link in the menu:

```
<a href="#about">WHO WE ARE</a>
```

And this is the DOM object it scrolls to

```
<section id="about"> <h2>Who We Are</h2> ... </section>
```

And the click listener is on line 128 of http://www.formationstone.com/wp-content/themes/Ignyte/includes/main-scripts.js?ver=4.9.5 line

```
jQuery('#menu a[href]').on('click', function(event) {
    if ($(this).parent().hasClass('telephone')) {}else{
    var target = jQuery(this).attr('href');
    if( target.length ) {
        event.preventDefault();
        jQuery('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: jQuery(target).offset().top+75
        }, 1000);
    }}
});
```

It takes the `href` attribute of the clicked link (which is `#about`) and uses it as a jQuery selector, e.g. `$('#about')` which is the `<section>`. And then it scrolls 75px below these section header with a 1 second animation. The thing you are looking for is in line 145: `event.preventDefault();`. This stops the browser from executing the default event, which would be calling the URL `#about`.

A side note: There are two ways to make a direct call to http://www.formationstone.com/#about work. With a named anchor:

```
<section id="about">
    <a name="about"></a>
    <h2>Who We Are</h2>
</section>
```

Or with a hash listener (that's what they are using, I just couldn't find it easily). It would be something like:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    if (window.location.hash) {
        var target = jQuery(window.location.hash);
        if( target.length ) {
            // scroll immediately without animation
            jQuery('html, body').animate({
                scrollTop: jQuery(target).offset().top+75
            });
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Everything past the `#` in a URL is mainly for the browser's benefit, not the server. `.htaccess` doesn't have much to do with this issue.

I'm not sure what SPA technology you're using, but using Angular as I do, the way I'd avoid having an anchor tag show in the URL is by *not* using Angular's router -- simply show and hide sections of your SPA by changing the visibility of the various sections directly.

One disadvantage of doing this is that a user can't bookmark a particular section of your app and return there reliably based on the URL they've bookmarked.

Comment: And that's the trick that the website in the example are using. They have a link target, so you can share/bookmark "detail" links while preventing the hashchange... I personally love the angular router (although it needs redirect rule on the webserver for direct calls).